# SharePoint task management issues

Tags: 2007, publishing-site

I am using SharePoint Server 2007 Enterprise with Windows Server 2008 Enterprise. I have the following requirements about `Task Management and want to know whether SharePoint Server 2007 can implement such feature.

And if not, what kind of Microsoft or non-Microsoft product could achieve such goals (and could integrate with SharePoint Server 2007). I prefer Microsoft product because I have requirement to integrate task management feature into SharePoint, and I think using Microsoft product is easier for integration with SharePoint. :-)

Requirements are,

1. For Task Management, task dependencies can be shown, and a big task can be divided into a couple of small tasks;
2. Task assignment is based on organization hierarchy. i.e. a department manager in organization chart could assign tasks to his employees, but not employee of other department managers.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

I know that [Brightwork's](http://www.brightwork.com/) pmPoint will do #1.  I'm not sure about #2.  Are you wanting a single task list that everyone's tasks will be in?  Why not break it up by department and then just roll up the tasks to a different page if you need that type of visability?  If you break it up by departments and then have an exec view that rolls up all of the tasks, then I'm pretty sure that brightwork will do what you are asking.

Comment: Could Project Server achieve my requirements?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have an experience with project server.

Answer (score 1):

MS Project with or without Project Server will meet these requirements and provide much more. With these tools you can use multiple hierarchies so that tasks can be presented in various groupings to meet the neeeds of various users.

Answer (score 0):

You could Task Master by Bamboo Solutions if you have a spare $900